# Need to find the AIR for Android SDK

Tags: android, air, air-android

I'm in a bind. I need to make changes to an AIR for Android application, and I don't have the SDK. I was signed up for Adobe's AIR for Android prerelease program, but I never downloaded the files. Now I'm responsible for making some changes to an existing app, and the prerelease site is shut down now. Is there anywhere where I can still get the latest SDK, or can I get it from someone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The Air SDK:

http://www.adobe.com/products/air/sdk/

The Android SDK:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Don´t know if you still have this problem, but the AIR Runtime for Android comes now in the Air 2.6 SDK download. Its in the path runtimes/air/android both for the emulator and the device.

Hope that helps.

Maria

Answer (score 0):

In slightly greater detail, AIR 2.5 shipped, so AIR for android was removed from the Labs site, and the pre-release shut down.

See the minuscule blog posting on labs:

http://blogs.adobe.com/labs/archives/2010/10/air-2-5-is-now-shipping.

> AIR 2.5 is now shipping and as a result AIR for Android content is no longer on Labs

The links given by AedonEtLIRA are where the released SDKS live.